# VLOOKUP: How do I match one column to another sheet and join them without losing data?

Tags: if-statement, filter, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, google-query-language

I have two sheets that look something like this:

```
Sheet1

id | phone | age
0    123     23
1    456     42
2    789     36
```

```
Sheet2
id | city | country
0   madrid  spain
1   nyc     usa
2   dubai   uae 
3   london  england
4   lisbon  portugal
```

My goal is to have a sheet that looks like this:

```
Sheet3
id | phone | age | city | country
0    123     23   madrid  spain  
1    456     42   nyc     usa
2    789     36   dubai   uae
3                 london  england
4                 lisbon  portugal
```

I've been using this formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({'Sheet1'!A$1:C$4, VLOOKUP('Sheet1'!A$1:A$4,{'Sheet2'!A$1:A$6, 'Sheet2'!B$1:C$6}, {2,3}, false)})
```

This is what I get:

```
Sheet3
id | phone | age | #N/A | #N/A
0    123     23   madrid spain
1    456     42   nyc    usa 
2    789     36   dubai  uae
```

So as you can see, it is leaving out the column headers from Sheet2 in the combined table and it leaves out any rows where the id doesn't match. How do I tell it to leave those rows in and leave the cells blank and include the column headers from Sheet2?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({A:C, IFNA(VLOOKUP(IF(A:A<>"", A:A, "×"), E:G, {2, 3}, 0)); 
 FILTER({E2:E, IFERROR(E2:F/0), F2:G}, NOT(COUNTIF(E2:E, A2:A)))}, 
 "where Col1 is not null order by Col1", 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This works. I've been trying to parse this out to understand each part, but I'm having a hard time doing that. Could you break it down some, please?

Comment: @KennaReagan sure. so VLOOKUP part is pretty much same that you used. from yellow sheet you take whole A:C then VLOOKUP A column in E column and return green F:G columns. (vlookup understands id 0 as empty cell so we added simple IF to filter out empty cells from A5:A to be paired with F2:G2 eg. we set empty cells of A5:A to × and since there is no × id in E column vlookup will not find anything so it will throw an error - therefore we wrap vlookup into IFNA to hide all errors due to no match) next part is FILTER formula which we put under the vlookup in array {} constellation.

Comment: @KennaReagan top part with vlookup outputs A:C = 3 columns + 2 columns of vlookup = which totals as 5 columns. to avoid array errors from {} all ranges put under each other needs to have same number of columns but range E:G has only 3 columns so we need to add 2 column into the middle. we use IFERROR and we take any two columns and divide them by 0. whatever it is or it is not in these two columns devising it by 0 will throw us an error and IFERROR will hide those errors so we end up with 2 empty columns.

Comment: @KennaReagan so we take E column followed by two empty columns followed by F:G columns and we filter it in such way with NOT(COUNTIF( that we bring over only green rows with ids that are not found in yellow A column. at this point we have top vlookup range followed by a lots of empty rows and followed by filter at the bottom... next we wrap all of it to QUERY and remove empty rows and order the rest by IDs. that's pretty much it.